# It is true that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(x<m \ \cap Y \leq k-x) f_{X}(x)dx= \int_{0}^{m}\mathbb{P}( Y \leq k-x) f_{X}(x)dx$?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be **independent** random variables. Then it is true that?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(x<m  \ \cap Y \leq k-x) f_{X}(x)dx= \int_{0}^{m}\mathbb{P}( Y \leq k-x) f_{X}(x)dx$$

And, how can I demonstrate it?

The whole demostration is the next:

$$\mathbb{P}(X \leq m \cap Y \leq k)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X<m  \ \cap Y \leq k-X |X=x) f_{X}(x)dx$$ where it`s used the total probability theorem in the continuos version (supposes X has density f_X)

Comment: Please show some context in the form of where this problem is from or what you have done to try to solve the problem.

Comment: Sure! It`s done! :)

Comment: I don't see it in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Observe that
$$\mathbb{P}(x < m \cap Y \le k-x) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{P}(Y \le k-x), & x < m \\ 0, &x \ge m. \end{cases}$$

Comment: And  how can I demostrate it Nate? Thank you. With it, the equality would be demonstrated, woudn´t it?

Comment: @Edin_91: It seems so clear that I'm not really sure what to say, but let's start with this.  Do you understand why $\mathbb{P}(3 > 4) = 0$?  Note that $\mathbb{P}$ is a map whose inputs are subsets of the sample space $\Omega$, so this is shorthand for $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega : 3 > 4\})$.  Now, no matter what $\omega$ is, it is not true that $3>4$, so $\{\omega \in \Omega : 3 > 4\} = \emptyset$.  Thus $\mathbb{P}(3 > 4) = \mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Nate. I understand what you have explainen. And I understand that  $\mathbb{P}(x < m \cap Y \le k-x) =\mathbb{P}(\emptyset)=0$ when $x>m$. So, when $x<m$, $\mathbb{P}(x < m \cap Y \le k-x)=\mathbb{P}( Y \le k-x)$ because we already know that $x<m$. \\ So it does not infuence X and Y to be independent. Correct?

Comment: @Edin_91: Yes, that's right.  The independence of $X,Y$ is not needed.